# List Comprehension with Mapping to Get a New Dataframe When Its Column Value Contains At Least One Element in A Given List

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I have a dataframe `df`. I eventually want to have a new dataframe that column `'question'` in `df` contains an element in a list `answer`.

```
answer = ['a','b','c','d','e']
df = pd.DataFrame({'question': ['a,b', 'b,c', 'z', 'f,e', 'x', 'd']})

>>> df
  question
0      a,b
1      b,c
2        z
3      f,e
4        x
5        d
```

I want the desired output dataframe to be:

```
>>> new_df
  question
0      a,b
1      b,c
3      f,e
5        d
```

And this is what I have simplified so far.

```
for y in answer:
    new_df = df[df['question'].map(lambda x: y in x)]
```

###### I came up with something like this and got the following error:

```
new_df = df[df['question'].map(lambda x: y in x for y in answer)]

TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

How can I get a new dataframe that satisfies the condition in one line of code by using list comprehension?

Comment: Is list comprehension is mandatory?

Comment: Not really lol. I just wanna do it that way for practice purpose. @Corralien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html?highlight=contains#pandas.Series.str.contains), [Pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html?highlight=concat#pandas.concat) and [DataFreame.sort_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with a comprehension-list:

```
df_result = pd.concat([df[df['question'].str.contains(a)] for a in answer]).drop_duplicates().sort_index()
```

But, if you ask me the above is not readable, So I let you the code above without list-comprehension to a good understanding:

```
list_dfs = []
for a in answer:
  # df_match will be a tiny dataframe with the matching.
  # For instance, In the first iteration will be:
  #      question
  # 0      a,b  
  df_match = df[df['question'].str.contains(a)]
  list_dfs.append(df_match)

df_result = pd.concat(list_dfs).drop_duplicates().sort_index()
print(df_result)
```

For both versions, the output is the same:

```
    question
0   a,b
1   b,c
3   f,e
5   d
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I need. Using `str.contains` to filter the df string and then `pandas.concat` is a brilliant idea.

Comment: `contains(a, regex=False)` will return a literal pattern, which avoids jupyter notebook annoying warning message.

Comment: Anytime! I'm glad this answer has been useful :D

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.isin` rather than list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'question': ['a,b', 'b,c', 'z', 'f,e', 'x', 'd']})
```

```
>>> df['question'].str.split(',') \
                  .apply(lambda x: len(set(x).intersection(answer)) != 0)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
Name: question, dtype: bool
```

New dataframe:

```
new_df = df[df['question'].str.split(',') \
                          .apply(lambda x: len(set(x).intersection(answer)) != 0)]
```

```
>>> new_df
  question
0      a,b
1      b,c
3      f,e
5        d
```

Comment: What if I have to do a regex split instead of `split(',')` How should I revise this? I tried `df[re.split(r'....', df['question'].str).apply....]` But it doesn't make sense here

Comment: Give a sample of your real  `question` column. Don't use `re.split`, prefer `pd.Series.str.split`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

Comment: It's a really complicated regex split which I have done preceding this cell of code. `pd.Series.str.split` is probably gonna not suitable since I don't want to skip spliting when it comes to circumstances comma between parenthesis like `(etc. engineer, doctor, accountant)`. I think `pd.Series.str.contains` might work better in this case. But really appreciate for sharing your thought and code.

Comment: `pandas.Series.str.extract` and then implement regex pattern could also be a way.